# Split Value Into Array separated List and display the Value as a "IMAGE"

Tags: php

I Have a Variable

> $a = 1,2,3,4;

split value into array separated by ',' using Explode

```
$explodeA = explode(",", $a)   
$sizeOfa = sizeof($explodeA);
```

Finally concatenate

> .png

into array listed values.

```
for($i = 0; $i < $sizeOfa; $i++)
    <img src="<?php echo $explodeA[$i]."."."png";?>">
```

But the images are not displayed, WHY?. I Have The Following Images

> 1.png, 2.png, 3.png, 4.png .

Comment: What do you get as result, when you look into the source code?

Comment: @Rizier123 he wont see anything with this wrong PHP syntax... 
Without closing php after the for() he is outputing <img and then he opens new <?php ...

Comment: Why not `echo "<img src=\"" . $explodeA[$i] . ".png\">";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some quotes and semicolon was missing. Try this:

```
$a ="1,2,3,4";

$explodeA = explode(",",$a);

$sizeOfa = sizeof($explodeA);

for($i=0;$i<$sizeOfa;$i++)
    echo '<img src="'.$explodeA[$i].'.png">';
```

Comment: It Only Displays 1,2,3,4.png. Any Solutions There. Please Help Us

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using foreach, this is easier to use.

```
$a = '1,2,3,4';

$explodeA = explode(",", $a);   

foreach($explodeA as $source) {
    echo '<img src="' . $source . '.png">';
}
```

Comment: Can't you too see the syntax errors??

Comment: @DamienPirsy Sorry, I'm kinda sick atm :p. So I didn't notice it at first.

Comment: @Thaillie Can you run this code and can't you see the errors

Answer (score 2):

Use foreach as it will automatically loop over the items available in array

```
$a = 1,2,3,4;

$explodeA = explode(",", $a)   

foreach($explodeA as $item) {
    echo "<img src=".$item.".png" />";
}
```

Comment: syntax errors and its the same answer as @Thaillie ..

Comment: @Svetlio i didn't notice that.

Comment: super@tahir. but a problem in my question i have 3 values

Comment: $a = 1,2,3,4 and $b = 3,4,5,6 and $c =7,8,9,10

Comment: i need to display variable $a as a image and others as a number. These three are must in the table

Comment: @BalaMurugan i did not understand what you are trying to say. Can you please elaborate your problem. like how does you want to appear the data?

Comment: $a = 1,2~3,4 and $b=5,6 and $c = 7,8 i need to display these values in table. like us row1:  1.png, 2.png | 5 | 7|  row2: 3.png, 4.png | 6 | 8 what can i do. i cant display images...@tahir

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$a = '1,2,3,4';

$explodeA = explode(",",$a);

$sizeOfa = sizeof($explodeA);

for($i=0;$i<$sizeOfa;$i++){
?>
    <img src="<?php echo $explodeA[$i].'.png'; ?>">
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In `echo '<img src="full path of an image'.$explodeA[$i].'.png"/></img>';`
I think in `src` of `img` you should add full path an image instead of only image name.